# How to create two-dimensional array based on two list

Tags: java

I have such class:

```
@Data
public class Pair {

private List<Long> firstCurrency; // 1, 5, 7, 2

private List<Long> secondCurrency; // 2 , 9 , 11 , 5  
}
```

Based on those two list I would like to create such class:

```
@Data
public class Pair {
private List<OwnPair> pairs;
}
```

where OwnPair:

```
@Data
public class OwnPair {
    private Long timestamps;
    private Long values;
}
```

so, at the and i will have 4 object inside of pairs (( 1,2) , (5,9), (7,9) , (2,5))

**Note :**

The two lists will always be the same size, and the indexes just have to match the order. I have a problem because i don't know how to iterate over two lists at once.

How i could spell the two lists.

Comment: create an indexed for loop and access both list with the same index.

Answer (score 1):

If your size is determined anyway (if you meant that by "same size"), you can also use arrays, because Lists only make sense when the amount of entries is not determined.

```
long[] firstCurrency = {1,5,7,2};
long[] secondCurrency = {2,9,11,5};

long[][] merged = new long[firstCurrency.length][2];

for(int i = 0; i<firstCurrency.length; i++)
{
    merged[i][0] = firstCurrency[i];
    merged[i][1] = secondCurrency[i];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(merged));
```

outputs: `[[1, 2], [5, 9], [7, 11], [2, 5]]`

If you really want to use lists though, just replace the `.length` with `.size()` and the array access with `.get(i)`.

Also, there is no need to wrap this into an own class.

Answer (score 0):

A stream based approach would be to create an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) over the size of the lists. This is assuming that both the lists have the same size:

```
List<OwnPair> collect = IntStream.range(0, firstCurrency.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new OwnPair(firstCurrency.get(i), secondCurrency.get(i)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[`range()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) is creating an `IntStream` ranging from 0 to 3, then for each index [`mapToObj()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj(java.util.function.IntFunction)) maps the index to an `OwnPair`. Here, a constructor accepting the two values is assumed. The result is then collected to a `List` but can of course be changed to whatever is needed.